# Does ecryptfs encrypt the contents of each file or just the directory tree?

Tags: ecryptfs

I recently had a harddrive crash and it seems it has corrupted the ecryptfs files(and ofc some others nearby). I wanted to know if I can still recover the content as I saw that there were actually some files in the *.Private* directory.

Comment: Ecryptfs is not full disk encryption.  It just excrypts the individual files.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes I read about that but does it really encrypt the file or just the pointer to that file aka the inode?

Comment: It encrypts the file; Attempt to open the file; it will be encrypted;

Comment: @Ramhound ok thanks. I tried to but I'm not sure weather it really was encrypted or just was an executable file. So if I were to image the disk I would still not read those encrypted files.

Comment: Why don't you open a file you known isn't an application?

Comment: @Ramhound that because my whole Home folder is encrypted and I'm from a Live USB stick and all the folders inside home directory have cryptic names. IDK which is which

Comment: FYI, I wrote a utility, ecryptfs-recover-private, that helps recover Ubuntu encrypted home directories: http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2011/04/introducing-ecryptfs-recover-private.html  Full disclosure: I'm one of the authors and maintainers of eCryptfs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ecryptfs encrypts the individual files (typically using AES encryption if I recall).   The data is encrypted at rest.

That said, there are significant limitations to slightly older (think 2015 and earlier) implementations, particularly [CV-2014-9687](http://www.securiteam.com/securitynews/5PP302AGAA.html) among others - making it better then nothing, but not in the same league as LUKS full disk encryption.  (Generally this package has a less-then-stellar security record, but its certainly better then nothing, and useful when you need to sync at  a file - just don't forget to back up the .encfs? file as well.

Comment: Less than stellar?  Perhaps you're confusing eCryptfs with encfs (since, later in your response, you talk about .encfs, rather than .ecryptfs).  Full disclosure: I'm one of the authors and maintainers of eCryptfs.

Comment: You are probably right, but when I researched full disk vs file encryption all (Linux) file encryption options came up wanting.y I have a vague recollection had to do a weakened encryption when your adversary had at least 2 copies of your data with some changes allowing drastic reduction of key space.